# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: is there a way to always forward to the https version of an url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, paperclip

So, in some of my database records, there is an object, "content" that has a body, much like a document would. Sometimes the body has URL that point to images on my app server. Many of these URLs are HTTP.

Is there anyway to redirect all HTTP requests to HTTPS?

I'm using Rails 2.3.8
and the Paperclip gem

Comment: So you want to change the links that are present in the content from http:// to https:// ?

Comment: kind of. with over 20k records with possible http links in them, just changing them would be hard, I think... which is why I was thinking it might be easier to just redirect them. maybe at the controller level? idk

Comment: These links point to images? If you are hosting using Apache or Nginx you can just redirect the URL's with a configuration change. Or you can do a search and replace rake task that converts the URL's

Answer (score 0):

Because some browser security settings will block HTTP assets when viewing a HTTPS page, you don't want to do this at the web server (e.g. mod_rewrite) level since some browsers won't make it that far.

You don't want to handle this at the view or controller level - the model is where you enforce business rules like keep it all HTTPS.

1) Prevent HTTP links from being saved

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  before_validation :force_https
  def force_https
    unless body.nil?
      self.body.gsub! /http:\/\/my\.app\.server/, 'https://my.app.server'
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

2) Clean up existing content

Fire up console and run this:

```
Content.all.each do |c|
  c.update_attribute 'body', 
     c.body.gsub(/http:\/\/my\.app\.server/, 'https://my.app.server')
end
```